# Is it OK to use name of a function as a name of unrelated class in PHP?

Tags: php

I have seen similar questions asking about making functions like `function myClass(){return new myClass();}`. My question is a bit different - I want to make a class and name using a word that coincidentally is used as a name of PHP function.

For example, a round of competition should be an object of class `Round`. But there is also a PHP function `Round()` (usually typed as `round()`) Do I risk running into problems or this is fine?

I know Laravel has `Log` class but I am not sure that "Laravel does it" is enough to be sure.

Comment: If you are giving same name to method ditto of class's then that method will be considered as constructor of that class. If will call automatically, once object of that class will be initiated

Comment: @rahul_m The question is not about naming methods. It's just "Is it fine to name a class `Round` if such function is already defined in PHP itself?"

Comment: Go a other way and use `namespaces`! Define something like `namespace myarea;  function round(){}` and you are fine, no problem with names. You can not use reserved words http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: I think round is reserved keyword, you should not use it.

Comment: @rahul_m   __giving same name to method ditto of class__ -- __DEPRECATED in PHP 7.0__  JustAsNote

Comment: Thanks mate, I will keep this in mind !

Comment: Seems not to cause any issue (tested on PHP 7.1 with : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/671fff2d00832e35f723760f5df93033814f7641).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even it works in [this example](http://codepad.org/9IEi2buP), but in some cases it will lead to Name collisions, using [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) is better and safer of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use `namespaces` to prevent name conflicts

```
namespace xyz {
   class round {
    function __construct(){
        print __METHOD__.'<br>';
    }
  }
  function strpos(){
      print __FUNCTION__.'<br>';
  }
}

namespace {

 use \xyz\round;

 new round();

 print round(1.234,2).'<br>';//original php

 \xyz\strpos();

 print strpos('abc','b').'<br>';//original php

}
```